# bundle install時にNetwork errorとなりrubygems.orgに接続できない

Tags: ruby, centos, rubygems, redmine, bundler

仮想マシンでRedmine4構築中にbundle installで下記のエラーが発生します。

```
# bundle install --without development test --path vendor
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Network error while fetching https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/nokogiri-1.1
```

環境：

- OS: CentOS7
- Gem 3.0.3
- Ruby 2.5.3
- bundle 2.0.1

※Proxyは使用していません。

試してみたもの：

- Gemfileのsource 'https//rubygems.org' → 'http//rubygems.org'
- bundleのバージョン '2.0.1' →　'1.6.4'
- `gem update --system`
- `gem update bundler`

以前は `bundle install` できていたのですが、ルータを新しいものに変更してからエラーが発生しています。直接的な原因ではないと思いますが...。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

仮想マシン上で、次の操作は成功しますか？

```
wget https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
```

成功していれば、rubygems.org には問題ないと思います。

---

ネットワークエラーには色々原因が考えられると思いますが、先日 Ubuntu で特定のルーターを経由したときだけ、gem install が失敗する問題に突き当たりましたので、それについて記載します。

**CentOS 7 の IPv6 を無効にしてみてください。**

*現在の rubygems.org は IPv6 に対応しています。*

問題の起きるルーターには IPv4 over IPv6 が設定されていたのですが、それが原因なのか、gem install 時の IPv6 接続にエラーが出ていました。

IPv4 を優先にすると、無事にネットワークエラーが解決されました。

---

IPv6 無効化については、例えば、このあたりが参考になりそうです。

- [How to Disable IPV6 on CentOS7](https://linuxhint.com/disable_ipv6_centos7/)